# Convert one object records to two object(parent and child) records

Tags: apex, trigger

I have one object named "Order_batch__c".I want to separate the data into two records one is parent object "order" and child object "order item"

```
order consists of fields : customer po,account name, customer id
order item consists of fields : nicomatic pin,quantity ordered
```

My requirement is to separate records in parent and child records .when ever there is an update in order batch records it has to update accordingly parent or child.

Trigger:

```
trigger orderitem on order_batch__c (after insert , after update) {
    order__c[] orders = new order__c[] {};
    order__c[] uporders=new order__c[]{};
    set<string> ids=new set<string>();
    set<string> ids1=new set<string>();
    map<string, order_batch__c> ObjMap = new map<string, order_batch__c>();
    for (order_batch__c ob : Trigger.new){
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
   orders.add(new order__c(Or_customer_PO_Number__c = ob.Or_customer_PO_Number__c,Account_code__c=ob.Or_customerid__c));
   ids.add(ob.Or_customer_PO_Number__c);
    }
     if(Trigger.isupdate)
        {
      if (ob.Or_customer_PO_Number__c != Null){
      ObjMap.put(ob.Or_customer_PO_Number__c, ob);
     }
     }
    }
    insert orders;

//list<order_batch__c> obc= new list<order_batch__c>([select id,Or_customer_PO_Number__c from order_batch__c where Or_customer_PO_Number__c in:ids Limit 1]);   
list<order__c> ord= new list<order__c>([select id,Or_customer_PO_Number__c,Account_code__c from order__c where Or_customer_PO_Number__c IN :ObjMap.KeySet()]);
    for (order__c ob : ord){
    order_batch__c obc=ObjMap.get(ob.Or_customer_PO_Number__c);
    uporders.add(new order__c(id=ob.id,Or_customer_PO_Number__c = obc.Or_customer_PO_Number__c,Account_code__c=obc.Or_customerid__c));     
    }
    if(uporders.size() > 0){
    update uporders;
    }  
    Order_Item__c[] upitems = new Order_Item__c[] {};
    Order_Item__c[] items = new Order_Item__c[] {};   
    Integer index = 0;
    for (order_batch__c ob : Trigger.new)
    {
    if(Trigger.isInsert)
        {
 items.add(new Order_Item__c(
                Name = ob.Or_Nicomatic_p_n__c,
                Client_PN__c = ob.Or_clientpn__c,
                Quantity__c = ob.Quantity_Ordered__c,
                Request_Date__c = ob.Requested_Date__c,
                Discount__c = ob.Discount__c,
                Price__c = ob.Unit_price__c,
                Order__c = orders[index].Id
                ));
        index++;
    }
 if(Trigger.isupdate)
 {
  ids1.add(ob.Or_Nicomatic_p_n__c);
 }
 }
    insert items;

List<Order_Item__c> orderlineitem=new list<order_item__c>([select id ,name,Order_customer_po_number__c from order_item__c where Order_customer_po_number__c IN :ObjMap.KeySet() and name in:ids1]);
for (order_item__c ob : orderlineitem){
    order_batch__c obc=ObjMap.get(ob.Order_customer_po_number__c);
   upitems.add(new order_item__c(id=ob.id,name = obc.Or_Nicomatic_p_n__c,Quantity__c = obc.Quantity_Ordered__c));     
          }
    if(upitems.size()>0){
    update upitems;
   }  
}
```

For this :insert is happening for both  parent and child (order,orderitem)
Update is happening for only parent .

update is not happening for child .Help me regarding this issue

Comment: Teja -- you might get more assistance if you a) reformatted your code to make it readable (proper indenting) and b) used common courtesies in your entreaty for assistance

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, I don't know exactly how your order system works, but here's what I see that appears to be different that may be the source of your problem:

```
if(Trigger.isInsert){
   orders.add(new order__c(Or_customer_PO_Number__c = ob.Or_customer_PO_Number__c,Account_code__c=ob.Or_customerid__c));
   ids.add(ob.Or_customer_PO_Number__c);   // <--- This line isn't repeated for if(Trigger.isupdate) to add line items
}
if(Trigger.isupdate)
{
   if (ob.Or_customer_PO_Number__c != Null){
       ids.add(ob.Or_customer_PO_Number__c); // Insert this line here to add the new line items to your PO    
       ObjMap.put(ob.Or_customer_PO_Number__c, ob)
   }
}
```

You run this query which applies to both after insert and after update conditions. Perhaps you meant to add an `if(isInsert)` clause here?

```
list<order__c> ord= new list<order__c>([select id,Or_customer_PO_Number__c,Account_code__c from order__c where Or_customer_PO_Number__c IN :ObjMap.KeySet()]);

// you then start this loop for both:

for (order__c ob : ord){ 
.
.
.
// if(Trigger.isInsert) you do the following:
         }
    items.add(new Order_Item__c(  
.
.
.
       {

// But  if(Trigger.isupdate) you do what's below. If this is to be an after insert loop, this code belongs elsewhere.
{
  ids1.add(ob.Or_Nicomatic_p_n__c); 
  // Are these from your query or did they get added through the line I added above? 
  // You're outside the trigger.new loop at this point in your trigger and aren't coming from there.
}
```

Next you do an insert followed by another query on line items

```
    insert items;
```

Perhaps you meant to add an `if(isUpdate) here?

```
List<Order_Item__c> orderlineitem=new list<order_item__c>([select id ,name,Order_customer_po_number__c from order_item__c where Order_customer_po_number__c IN :ObjMap.KeySet() and name in:ids1]);
```

Now you have this loop:

```
for (order_item__c ob : orderlineitem){
    order_batch__c obc=ObjMap.get(ob.Order_customer_po_number__c);
    upitems.add(new order_item__c(id=ob.id,name = obc.Or_Nicomatic_p_n__c,Quantity__c = obc.Quantity_Ordered__c));     
}
```

Then finally perform your update:

```
   if(upitems.size()>0){
    update upitems;
```

It appears to me that these two sections of code need to be isolated with if statements in order to solve your problems. I also suspect you need to add the statement I brought to your attention at the beginning which I suspect adds the line items to your order, but again, I don't know your system.